# RHive installation : Error in rhive.connect

Tags: r, hadoop, installation, rstudio

I was installing rhive on my cluster. I followed below link for installation.

https://github.com/nexr/RHive

Everything went smooth except last line. When i tried to connect r with hive server , it is throwing below exception.

```
> library(RHive)
Loading required package: rJava
Loading required package: Rserve
> rhive.connect("127.0.0.1", 10000, hiveServer2)
Error: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
>
```

Java Version

```
java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Does anyone has any clue here?

Comment: update your java installation

Comment: updated java version in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues got resolved when I changed my JAVA_HOME to jdk6. It looks like jdk7 is not supported.

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.36.x86_64/jre
```